# Parsing a nested sentence in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string-parsing

I am very new guy at PHP and trying to parse a line from database and get some neccesarray information in it.

**EDIT :**

I have to take the authors names and surnames like for first example line : 
the expected output should be :

`Ayse Serap Karadag`
`Serap Gunes Bilgili`
`Omer Calka`
`Sevda Onder`
`Evren Burakgazi-Dalkilic`

**LINE**

`[Karadag, Ayse Serap; Bilgili, Serap Gunes; Calka, Omer; Onder, Sevda] Yuzuncu Yil Univ, Sch Med, Dept Dermatol. %#[Burakgazi-Dalkilic, Evren] UMDNJ Cooper Univ Med Ctr, Piscataway, NJ USA.1`

I take this line from database. There are some author names which i have to take. 
The author names are written in `[]`. First their surnames which is separated with `,` and if there is a second author it is separated with `;`.

I have to do this action in a loop because i have nearly 1000 line like this.

My code is :

```
<?php

  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","authors");
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Correspounding_Author FROM paper Limit 10 ");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<br>";
  echo $row['Correspounding_Author'] ;
  echo "<br>";
  // do sth here
  }

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I am looking for some methods like `explode()` `substr` but as i mentioned at the beginning I cannot handle this nested sentence.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your code only fetches rows from a database; where's the attempt at actually handling the string value? And what's the expected output?

Comment: I editted my question, i need a author names and surnames. But there are lots of authors and there are 3 things that I have to parse but i cannot handle how can i do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
$pattern = '~(?<=\[|\G;)([^,]+),([^;\]]+)~';
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $row['Correspounding_Author'], $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    print_r(array_map(function($match) {
        return sprintf('%s %s', ltrim($match[2]), ltrim($match[1]));
    }, $matches));
}
```

It's a single expression that matches items that:

1. Start with opening square bracket `[` or continue where the last match ended followed by a semicolon,
2. End just before either a semicolon or closing square bracket.

See also: [PCRE Assertions](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php).

#### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Ayse Serap Karadag
    [1] => Serap Gunes Bilgili
    [2] => Omer Calka
    [3] => Sevda Onder
    [4] => Evren Burakgazi-Dalkilic
)
```

Answer (score 3):

The code inside your `while` loop should be:

```
preg_match_all("/\\[([^\\]]+)\\]/", $row['Correspounding_Author'], $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $match){
$exp = explode(";", $match);
    foreach($exp as $val){
    print(implode(" ", array_map("trim", array_reverse(explode(",", $val))))."<br/>");
    }
}
```

Comment: waow, that was impressive. This code is working that what i really want.